# Javascript click script is run multiple times after first execution

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have encountered a strange problem.
I have a function to be executed on clicking a link. The function has an alert and a database update via ajax.
I just noticed that if I click on the link after the first time, the alert appears several times. When I click it 2'nd time, it is executed 2 times, when I click 3'rd time it is executed 4 times so on.
This is my code.

```
$("a.action").on('click', function(e){

                if(confirm('Are you sure you want to set Action to 1?')){



                    var $index = $(this).closest('tr').index();
                    var ids = <?php echo json_encode($ids); ?>; 

                    table.row($(this).closest('tr')).remove().draw();
                    console.log("Row deleted");


                    //Set $action = 1;
                    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) 
                        {
                            console.log("Action set to 1");
                        }
                    };
                    xmlhttp.open("GET", "db_update.php?id="+ids[$index], true);
                    xmlhttp.send();

                }
                return true;

            });
```

Comment: post you html code

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery Ajax when you are already using jQuery?

Comment: My guess is that you have more code in that event handler. Could you share it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use
    event.preventDefault();

https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/